# Join two views in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

view1

```
+------+---------------+    
|PERSON  | CONTACTLIST |   
+------+---------------+ 
| A  |      CONT1      |   
| A  |      CONT2      |
| A  |      CONT5      |
| B  |      CONT1      |
| B  |      CONT3      |
| C  |      CONT2      |
+------+---------------+
```

View2

```
+------+------------------+    
|PERSON  | MEETINGS WITH  |   
+------+------------------+ 
| A  |      CONT7         |   
| A  |      CONT8         |
| A  |      CONT1         |
| A  |      CONT2         |
| B  |      CONT1         |
| B  |      CONT3         |
| B  |      CONT4         |
| C  |      CONT1         |
| C  |      CONT2         |
| C  |      CONT3         |
| C  |      CONT4         |
| C  |      CONT5         |
+------+---------------+
```

Wanted Result

```
+------+------------------+ -------+   
|PERSON  | MEETINGS WITH  |        |
+------+------------------+ -------+
| A  |      CONT7         |    0   |
| A  |      CONT8         |    0   |
| A  |      CONT1         |    1   |
| A  |      CONT2         |    1   |
| B  |      CONT1         |    1   |
| B  |      CONT3         |    1   |
| B  |      CONT4         |    0   |
| C  |      CONT1         |    0   |
| C  |      CONT2         |    1   |
| C  |      CONT3         |    0   |
| C  |      CONT4         |    0   |
| C  |      CONT5         |    0   |
+------+---------------+  + -------+
```

I have "View 1" contains the contact list of each Person! 
One Person can meet multiple contact , the meeting can be with one contact in his contact List or not!

I want to put a flag which indicates if the meeting was with a contact already in the contact list or not !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this then

```
select v2.PERSON, 
       v2.[MEETINGS WITH],
       case when v1.PERSON is null then 0 else 1 end as FLAG
from   view2 v2
  left outer join view1 v1 on v2.PERSON = v1.PERSON and v2.[MEETING WITH] = v1.CONTACTLIST
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    V.PERSON,
    V.[MEETINGS WITH],
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM 
            view1 
        WHERE 
            view1.PERSON = V.PERSON AND 
            view1.CONTACTLIST = V.[MEETINGS WITH]
     ) Counts
 FROM
     View2 V
```